# Android MediaCodec: Backlink to input

Tags: android, video

I'm receiving video data via RTP/H.264 (Profile Baseline). I'm building a complete NAL unit (using the NAL (Network Abstraction Limit) delimiter 0x09) and pushing this to the MediaCodec. Afterwards I'm rendering the decoded image via OpenGL to a SurfaceTexture. This does work well so far.

Now I need to know in my rendering calls which video frame is currently rendered. So I need meta information attached to the video frame later in the rendering part.

My first idea was to use a simple queue:

1) queue.offer(videoFrameId)
2) mediaCodec.queueInputBuffer()
3) mediaCodec.deqeueOutputBuffer()
4) mediaCodec.releaseOutputBuffer()

Then on the rendering side:

1) onFrameAvailable(SurfaceTexture)
2) queue.poll()
3) render()

But this is quickly out of sync. There are more calls to the MediaCodec.queueInputBuffer than onFrameAvailable(). It appears as if a video frame is build from multiple NAL units.

Are there any means to get a reference from the original video frame to the rendering? I'm limited to the SDK 19 API.

Thank you